# How to convert between an Object[] and an interface (IProject[]) in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, object, interface

I have an Object[] in Java and want to convert it to IProject[], which is a Java interface (org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject), in order to write a plugin for eclipse.

Is this possible?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert the array itself - arrays know the type of their slots, so you can't just cast an instance of `Object[]` to an expression of type `IProject[]`, even if the array happens to contain only instances of `IProject` (unless you happen to have a variable of type `Object[]` which actually points to an instance of `IProject[]`).

Instead, you'll need to make a new array with the same contents:

```
Object[] objects;
IProject[] projects = new IProject[objects.length];
System.arraycopy(objects, 0, projects, 0, objects.length);
```

Array stores are dynamically type-checked, so if your `Object[]` contains any objects which are not instances of `IProject`, you'll get an `ArrayStoreException`.

Answer (score 2):

are the Objects in `Object[]` instances of `IProject` ?

see [casting Object array to Integer array error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1115230/307767)