# How can I cast an Object array to an array of arrays of integers

Tags: java

This is a bit of a contrived example to get across the situation I'm encountering, but basically, I have an array of Objects that in reality contains arrays of integers, and I'm trying to cast it as such. Here is a code snippet that simulates this situation:

```
Object[] foo = new Object[3];
foo[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
foo[1] = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
foo[2] = new int[] { 7, 8, 9 };
int[][] bar = (int[][]) foo;
```

When I try to do this, I get the exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[I`

Is there a way to do this without copying the array (which I may not want to do since `foo` will be very large in production)? If not, why not?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error/8220245#8220245

Comment: Thanks, but the original goal was to do it without copying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't change the intrinsic type of a Java object by casting it.  That includes arrays.  The object's type is fixed when the object is allocated, and cannot be changed.

So casting an `Object[]` to `int[][]` will never work.

In this case, while `int[][]` is a subtype of `Object[]`, this is not sufficient for the typecast to be allowed at runtime.  The actual rule in the JLS ([5.5.3. Checked Casts at Run Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.3)) is this:

> *"Here is the algorithm to check whether the run-time type R of an object is assignment compatible with the type T which is the erasure (§4.6) of the type named in the cast operator. If a run-time exception is thrown, it is a `ClassCastException`." ...*
>
> *"If R is a class representing an array type RC[], that is, an array of components of type RC:"*
>
> - *"If T is an array type TC[], that is, an array of components of type TC, then a run-time exception is thrown unless one of the following is true:"*
>
>   - *"TC and RC are the same primitive type."*
>   - *"TC and RC are reference types and type RC can be cast to TC by a recursive application of these run-time rules for casting."*

In this case TC is `int[]` and RC is `Object` and `Object` *cannot* be cast to `int[]`.  Hence you get an exception.

To illustrate why this *must* happen, consider this (hypothetical) example:

```
   Object[] foo = new Object[3];
   foo[0] = new Object();
   int[][] bar = /* foo */
   int[] mystery = bar[0];
```

Assuming that it is possible to "cast" the value of `foo`, what should the `mystery` variable point to?  It can't be an `int[]` because we didn't allocate one.  It can't be an `Object` instance because that would break static typing.

In fact, the "cast" has to be illegal, or else Java's static type system falls apart.

---

> The difference between your example and mine is that foo is not actually an array of arrays of integers, whereas in my case it is. Why can the VM not see the "actual" type of the object?

The point is that static typing is (primarily) enforced by the compiler not by the JVM.  While the JVM could (in theory) figure out that the types are OK at runtime (and throw exceptions if they are not), the compiler cannot do this because it cannot determine **in general** what the types are going to be.

---

> Unfortunately I'm not actually creating the array myself.  I'm getting it from another function and the `Object[]` rather than `int[][]` is, as far as I can tell, the side effect of some serialization that I have no control over.

Unfortunately you have to either copy the array ... or use it as an `Object[]` and cast the elements to `int[]` to use them; e.g.

```
Object[] foo = new Object[3];
foo[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
foo[1] = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
foo[2] = new int[] { 7, 8, 9 };
...
int nine = ((int[]) (foo[2]))[2];
```

There is no "trust me it is really an `int[][]`" option in Java.

If this a side-effect of serialization then the serialization is broken ... in some sense.  Certainly, this won't happen with the standard Java Object Serialization protocol / implementation.  That *preserves* the types of the objects ... unless you explicitly override them in the `readObject` / `writeObject` methods, etcetera.

Comment: Just trying to gain a firm understanding of this, obviously you're right about the way it functions--the difference between your example and mine is that foo is not actually an array of arrays of integers, whereas in my case it is. Why can the VM not see the "actual" type of the object?

Comment: While correct, this does not solve the OP's problem. The solution is to access the `int[]`, as I humbly submit my answer does :-)

Comment: @andy256 casting would definitely work, but I'm actually also really curious about WHY this does not work, so this is very useful.

Comment: @andy256 - No.  The *correct* answer is to do this: `Object[] foo = new int[3][];` ... and get rid of the type cast.

Comment: @StephenC unfortunately I'm not actually creating the array myself--I'm getting it from another function and the `Object[]` rather than `int[][]` is, as far as I can tell, the side effect of some serialization that I have no control over.

Comment: @Catherine Why the aversion towards copying the array? `System.arraycopy()` is native and quite fast.

Comment: @arshaji it's undesirable since there may be billions of entries in my top level array. It's not out of the question, I was just wondering if there's a way to avoid doing it (and at this point, I'd just really like to have a *firm* understanding what the reason is for not being able to cast an object to its "actual" type, which is why I'm still pursuing this line of questioning :))

Comment: @Catherine Sure, I understand. Note that arrays have a maximum length of ~2.1 billion.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks, this has been extremely helpful. Is there any reading material on the topic that you could point me towards?

Comment: @arshajii - You are correct about subtyping, but it turns out that the real reasoning for the failure (per the JLS) doesn't involve that at all.  (In fact, subtyping explains why this is NOT a compile time error!)  I have corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since `foo` is array of objects it means it can contain anything, not only array of integers so compiler cant allow you to cast it to array of integers only because you know that it is inside.

If you want to use `int[][] bar` reference you will have to create separate `int [3][]` array first and copy content of `foo` to that array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast each object as you access it.

```
    Object[] foo = new Object[3];
    foo[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    foo[1] = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
    foo[2] = new int[] { 7, 8, 9 };
    int[] foo2 = (int[])foo[2];
    System.out.println("foo[2,2]="+((int[])foo[2])[2]);
```

You should also wrap this in `try ... catch`, if you think the contents could be non-ints.

Edit: simplify code.