# how to cast intent's extra object[] to MyClas[]

Tags: java, android, serialization, casting, parcelable

I have this code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.offers_list);

    Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
    if (callingIntent != null) {
        Bundle extras = callingIntent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Offer[] offers = (Offer[]) extras
                    .getSerializable(PublicMacros.OFFERS_LIST);
        }
    }
```

and i get this error after executing

`02-19 01:59:52.291: E/AndroidRuntime(26440): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.zoomer.offers.Offer[]`

how can i cast properly?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1115234/951894).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to cast an `object[]` to a `T[]` where `T` is an abitrary class.

But you can use

```
Offer[] array = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length, Offer[].class);
```

Where a is the returned array from

```
extras.getSerializable(PublicMacros.OFFERS_LIST);
```

Or you can iterate over each element in the array and cast each one for its own.

Comment: what is the best practice for sending Offer[] from one activity to another?

Comment: what do you mean with activity?

Comment: android's Activity. I want to send the data from one activity to another