# File cannot be converted to apparently, file

Tags: java, file, type-conversion, classcastexception

After I converted an ArrayList to an Object[]. I then tried to convert that to an File[] which throws a ClassCastException. When I ran it through the Eclipse debugger, I see that the Object[] contains two File objects.

```
List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
list.add(new File("foo.bar")); list.add(new File("foo.bar.bar"));
Object[] objlist = list.toArray();
File[] flist = (File[]) objlist;
```

Running this throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.io.File;
at sphinx.file.ResourceGetter.getResources(ResourceGetter.java:37)
at sphinx.test.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

Eclipse tells me this:

```
Name: objlist.[0] Value: java.io.File
Value: objlist.[1] Value: java.io.File
```

I do not understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
File[] flist = list.toArray(new File[list.size()]);
```

OR

```
File[] flist = list.toArray(new File[]{});
```

You can't cast `Object[]` to `File[]`

Read more at similar post [casting Object array to Integer array error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error)

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. That is so stupid that you have to tell java this though.