# Creating a Generic Array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, constructor

Im having a big problem with this code: I need to create my own Merge Method without using java´s Merge Method.

```
public static <T extends Comparable> T[] merge(T[] a, T[] b){
    T[] c = (T[]) new Object[a.length + b.length];  

    /*
     *
     * More code
     *
     *
    */
    return c;
}
```

The problem is that in runtime I have this error:
***java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;***
I have already looked for this problem, and the solution is using Reflection.

The problem i have it in this line: T[ ] c = (T[ ]) new Object[a.length + b.length];

The problem is that I dont understand how to use it, have already try using reflection in many different ways but i can´t solve this.

I really appreciate any answer and tell me where should I change my code.

Comment: How about `Arrays.copyOf`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8220245/303939

Comment: (rawtypes! Should be `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, or better `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.)

Answer (score 4):

You could create an array of the same type as the input arrays, using reflection - something like this:

```
if(a.getClass() != b.getClass()) // or .equals if you prefer. It doesn't matter for Class objects
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arrays don't have the same type");

T[] c = Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), a.length + b.length);
```

Note that it is impossible to use something like `T.class`. Note also that this won't work as expected for cases like:

```
Comparable[] result = <Comparable>merge(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3}, new Integer[] {4, 5, 6});
```

as the result will be an `Integer[]` instead of a `Comparable[]`. However, it is the closest you can do without passing Comparable.class to the function, or pre-allocating the result array before calling it.

Or you could use `Arrays.copyOf` as suggested by Ming-Tang, and then fill the array with `null` (otherwise it starts with a copy of `a`):

```
if(a.getClass() != b.getClass()) // or .equals
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arrays don't have the same type");

T[] c = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + b.length);
Arrays.fill(c, null);
```

This has the same issues.

Comment: Because of the bizarre and unnatural behaviour of arrays, you should choose the "greatest common superclass". (Code for which is left as an exercise for the interested reader.) When I say "should", you should follow @immibis' advice and use `List`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Note that I wrote both answers, because either one could be best for the OP's application. (Although one would certainly hope, for his/her sanity, that the List one works)

Comment: Heh, didn't realise it was the same person. Reference arrays were badly messed up (not that `System.arraycopy` is a nice way of dealing with arrays).

Comment: you need to cast the result of `Array.newInstance()` to `T[]`

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `List` instead.

```
public static <T extends Comparable> List<T> merge(List<T> a, List<T> b){
    List<T> c = new ArrayList<T>(a.size() + b.size());

    /*
     *
     * More code
     *
     */
    return c;
}
```

This might not be an option if some other part of your code forces you to use arrays in `merge`.