# java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;at com.java.Test.Test.main(Test.java:16)

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new CountingGenerator.String(12).next());
        List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(new Integer(1));
        list.add(new Integer(2));

        Integer[] c = {1,3,3};
        //throw an exception:
        c = (Integer[]) list.toArray();
    }
}
```

I wonder why this happened ? Integer is a subclass of Object,so it should be Ok instead! please answer me deeply! I want know why? what's the principle ?

Comment: List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();why "list.toArray() " is an Object array????

Comment: you might want to take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error

Comment: There is no automatic recursive cast to cast Arrays of type A to type B. You have to do that manually or by using dedicated methods like 'Arrays.Copyof()'.

Comment: ”you can't treat a list of Integer IS-A list of Object “ thanks tom!thanks toni!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line

```
 c=(Integer[]) list.toArray();
```

to

```
c= list.toArray(c); // add c as parameter
```

In your `list.toArray();` returns `Object[]` and JVM doesn't know how to blindly downcast `Object[]` to `Integer[]`.

```
public Object[] toArray()      //return Object type array
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) //Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection; the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array
```

[Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray%28%29)

Comment: you can't treat a list of Integer IS-A list of Object!