# using Constructor without "new" word in java

Tags: java, reflection

So I'm trying to learn to use Reflection in java(so i think its called), so I did a little project to make an object without the optimal Constructor pattern with the "new" word.

Unfortunately, it shows me an error for the class type array for the constructor. Here is my project:

SomeClass.java:

```
public class SomeClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    classes.add(Integer.class);
    classes.add(String.class);
    classes.add(Boolean.class);
    Class[] classesArray = (Class[]) classes.toArray(); //here is where it showes the error

    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    objects.add(2452);
    objects.add("sfhfshsf");
    objects.add(true);
    Object[] studentObjects = objects.toArray();

    Student student = null;
    try {
        student = Student.class.getConstructor(classesArray).newInstance(
                studentObjects);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(student);

}
```

}

Student.java:

```
public class Student {
int studendID = 0;
String studentName = "";
boolean isSome1 = false;

public Student() {
}

public Student(int studendID, String studentName, boolean isSome1) {
    this.studendID = studendID;
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.isSome1 = isSome1;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [studendID=" + studendID + ", studentName="
            + studentName + ", isSome1=" + isSome1;
}
```

}

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Class;
at SomeClass.SomeClass.main(SomeClass.java:16)
```

What is the right way to do this? Help please.

Comment: You cannot cast array of one type to array of another - problem is addressed here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because the bulk of the problem is not in converting a list to an array, but in what goes onto the list in the first place.

Comment: In this case, rather than converting a List to an array, just create the array directly: `Class<?>[] classes = { Integer.class, String.class, Boolean.class };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use varargs to simplify this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Student student = Student.class
                             .getConstructor(Integer.class, String.class, Boolean.class)
                             .newInstance(2452, "sfhfshsf", true);

    System.out.println(student);
}
```

The problem you were having was that `toArray()` only returns an `Object[]` not a `Class[]` and it cann't be just cast to one.

What you could have done was.

```
Class[] classesArray = (Class[]) classes.toArray(new Class[0]);
```

Comment: @liranahum Try the much short syntax as well.

Answer (score 3):

You get an error because `toArray` returns an array of `Object`s. There is a [fix for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9572795/335858), but there is an easier way to construct an array of `Class` objects:

```
Class[] classesArray = new Class[] {
    Integer.TYPE, String.class, Boolean.TYPE
};
```

Note the use of [`.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE) instead of `.class` for `Integer` and `Boolean`. This is because your constructor takes *primitive* `int` and `boolean`, not `Integer` and `Boolean`.

Comment: yes, you were right! after adding "new Class[0]" in my "toArray()" function, i got another error, and changing to TYPE instead of class, did help me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Student class does not have a constructor that accepts a Class[], hence the exception.

You should  use either

```
 Student student = Student.class.getConstructor().newInstance();//calling no-args constructor

 or

 Student student = Student.class.getConstructor(Integer.class, String.class, Boolean.class).newInstance(10, "Mark', true);
```