# How to add a private key to Windows Cert Store programmatically

Tags: java, windows, security, certificate, keystore

I extracted a Key and its certification chain from a JKS, and now I'm trying to add this key to the Windows Keystore using Java.

To load my JKS I did the following:

```
    String jksPath = "D:\\mykeystore.jks";
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(jksPath);
    keystore.load(fIn, "12345678".toCharArray());
```

Then I get the key and the certification chain:

```
    Key key = keystore.getKey("res1", "12345678".toCharArray());
    Certificate[] cchain = keystore.getCertificateChain("res1");
```

So far so good, then I try to add this key to my Windows Keystore:

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    ks.load(null, null);
    ks.setKeyEntry("myKey", key, "12345678".toCharArray(), cchain);
```

And **BOOM**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.security.cert.Certificate; cannot be cast to [Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;
>       at sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:402)
>       at sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore$MY.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:62)
>       at java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:909)

Exception thrown due to the *setKeyEntry* call.

**P.S: when I use the same syntaxe on a JKS type of Keystore no exception is thrown.**

Answer (score 3):

It seems there's a clumsy bit of java code in the implementation of sun.security.mscapi.KeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(). It tries to convert an **array** of Certificates ("[Ljava.security.cert.Certificate", notice the prefix in the class name) to an **array** of X509Certificates (" [Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate"), which is not something java ever allows you to do with a simple cast expression (e.g. see [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error) of a similar mistake).

All I did in a similar situation is to pass the certificate array to the keyStore.setKeyEntry() method call as a X509Certificate array, rather than a simple Certificate array.