# How to cast Object[] to int[] java?

Tags: java, types, casting

This leads to complie error, I think this is because int is not inherited from Object, but is there any solution without traversing every item to do casting?

```
Object[] A1 ={1,2,3,4};
int [] B1 = (int[]) A1;
```

There is no problem with casting to Integer

```
Object[] A1 ={1,2,3,4};
Integer [] B1 = (Integer[]) A1;
```

I know we can do

```
   int [] C = new int[B1.length];
   for(int i=0;i<B1.length;i++)
     C[i] = Integer.valueOf(B[i]);
```

But, is there any auto casting method?

Comment: No, because `int` is not the same as `Integer`.

Comment: You can. What you are attempting is the reverse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error

Comment: Now that you've fixed your title, the answer is that you declared the array as `Object[]`, so that's what it is, forever. No upcast can change that.

Comment: `Integer [] B1 = (Integer[]) A1;` - that might not be a compile-time error, but [it is a run-time error](http://ideone.com/4qWchz).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have acknowledged in your question, `int` does not extend `Object` so the cast makes no sense and the compiler correctly complains.

Likely the safest and easiest way to achieve this is:

```
Object[] objects = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] ints = Arrays.stream(objects).mapToInt(o -> (int)o).toArray();
```

Not particularly elegant, but then again neither is storing an array of integers in an array of `Object` :-)

Comment: Why not `Arrays.stream(objects).mapToInt(o -> (int)o)`?

Comment: If that was your concern, `o -> (Integer)o` would be equally valid.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to *cast* an `Object[]` to an `int[]`, even if all the objects in the source array are `Integer` objects (like your example), because all the values need to be *unboxed*, not just cast.

```
Object[] A1 = {1,2,3,4};
```

That statement is actually auto-boxing the 4 integer literals for you, so the compiler is turning it into this:

```
Object[] A1 = new Object[4];
A1[0] = Integer.valueOf(1);
A1[1] = Integer.valueOf(2);
A1[2] = Integer.valueOf(3);
A1[3] = Integer.valueOf(4);
```

As can be seen from this decompilation:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.Exception;
  Code:
     0: iconst_4
     1: anewarray     #3                  // class java/lang/Object
     4: dup
     5: iconst_0
     6: iconst_1
     7: invokestatic  #19                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    10: aastore
    11: dup
    12: iconst_1
    13: iconst_2
    14: invokestatic  #19                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    17: aastore
    18: dup
    19: iconst_2
    20: iconst_3
    21: invokestatic  #19                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    24: aastore
    25: dup
    26: iconst_3
    27: iconst_4
    28: invokestatic  #19                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    31: aastore
    32: astore_1
    33: return
```

Any solution must do the traversing of every item to unbox the values, whether explicitly or implicitly.

Various ways to do that:

```
// Using cast to specific type and auto-unboxing (object cast)
int[] arr1 = new int[A1.length];
for (int i = 0; i < A1.length; i++)
    arr1[i] = (Integer)A1[i];

// Using cast to specific type and explicit unboxing
int[] arr2 = new int[A1.length];
for (int i = 0; i < A1.length; i++)
    arr2[i] = ((Integer)A1[i]).intValue();

// Using cast to more generic type and value extraction
int[] arr3 = new int[A1.length];
for (int i = 0; i < A1.length; i++)
    arr3[i] = ((Number)A1[i]).intValue();

// Using Java 8 streams with method references
int[] arr4 = Arrays.stream(A1)
                   .map(Integer.class::cast)
                   .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                   .toArray();

// Using Java 8 streams with lambda expression with auto-unboxing (primitive cast)
int[] arr5 = Arrays.stream(A1)
                   .mapToInt(o -> (int)o)
                   .toArray();
```