# Initialising array of private objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

To give you a bit of context, I am trying to build from scratch a HashMap using Java.

I have some issues when I am trying to instantiate an array of Nodes (Private class as defined below). I just want to instantiate the array first (in the constructor) and later I will update the same array (in methods not yet implemented).

Please find below the code to replicate the bug and the error message. Why the line `this.array = (K[]) new Object[this.size];` works and the line `this.buckets = (Node[]) new Object[this.size];` doesn't work?.

Is this achievable in Java or should I completely rethink the logic?

```
public class MyHashMapTest<K, V> {

    private class Node {
        K key;
        V val;
        Node next;

        Node(K k, V v, Node n) {
            key = k;
            val = v;
            next = n;
        }
    }

    private static final double defaultLoadFactor = 0.75;
    private static final int defaultSize = 16;

    private Node[] buckets;
    private K[] array;

    private int size;
    private int items;
    private double loadFactor;

    public MyHashMapTest() {
        this(defaultSize, defaultLoadFactor);
    }

    public MyHashMapTest(int initialSize) {
        this(initialSize, defaultLoadFactor);
    }

    public MyHashMapTest(int initialSize, double loadFactor) {
        this.size = initialSize;
        this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
        this.items = 0;
        this.array = (K[]) new Object[this.size];
        this.buckets = (Node[]) new Object[this.size];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyHashMapTest<String, String> a = new MyHashMapTest<String, String>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [casting Object array to Integer array error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, actually I know how to instantiate an array of integers. I am trying to instantiate an array of Nodes (as defined above). I have edited my post to better reflect this.

Comment: What's wrong with `this.buckets = new Node[this.size];`?

Comment: The thing is, you can't cast an array of a base type to an array of a derived type. You need to cast each element individually.

Comment: I get a compilation error: generic array creation

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me try to answer that properly.

Comment: You have to use reflection (specifically [`Array.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,int%29)) to programmatically create a generic array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Node` class is not static, which means it is bound to an instance of your outer class. You can work around that in two ways.

1. Create the array using `java.lang.reflect.Array`:

`this.buckets = (Node[]) Array.newInstance(Node.class, this.size);`

2. Make your nested class `static` (and add generics to it):

`private static class Node<A, B> {`

You can then define your `buckets` array of the generic types you need:

```
private Node<K, V>[] buckets;
```

And then you can just instantiate your array "normally":

```
this.buckets = new Node[this.size];
```