# Why do I get ClassCastException here?

Tags: java

I have created an array of generic type with a method that I saw in EffectiveJava, creating an array of objects and then casting it to convert it into an array of generic type.

But after creating an object looking to replace AnyType with String, when I add a string to the array I have the error.

```java
public class A<AnyType> {

    AnyType[] field;

    public A() {
        field = (AnyType[]) new Object[5];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A<String> object = new A<>();
        object.field[0] = "Test";
    }
}
```

I know I could do different things to do what I want in a better way, but what I want to know is in this case when the `ClassCastException` is generated and why.

It seems that it is when adding a string to the array, but why?

If when creating the object I set type String, shouldn't I be able to add a string to the array?

Comment: What's the actual error? Also, `(String[])new Object[5]` causes a class cast exception.

Comment: Arrays can't be casted in that way and the `Object` doesn't extend the `AnyType`. See [casting Object array to Integer array error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error)

Comment: Keep the `Object[]` then cast when you get Objects out. Check out [ArrayList](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)

Comment: The compiler warned you that the cast is not safe.  Either you did not have warnings enabled, or you chose to ignore that warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because JVM first loads the `main` method without calling `A` class constructor since `main` is `static`. After that you trying to create a typed instance of `A`, with `String` as a generic type. Therefore, in constructor, you are trying to case `Object[]` to `String[]`, which is impossible since `Object` is not a subtype of `String`. Thus, you get a `ClassCastException` at Runtime.

> If when creating the object I set type String, shouldn't I be able to add a string to the array?

Thats another question. You will be able to do so since [arrays are covariant in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C.23). But thats not what you are doing. You are not even getting your

> object.field[0] = "Test";

line of code executing. So fix the incorrect casting first :)

Comment: But why do I only get the ClassCastException if I add a String to the array? Because if I don't add anything, that is, I omit the line "object.field[0] = "Test";" and I only create the object like this "A<String> object = new A<>();", I don't get ClassCastException.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding @K6J4 question about why the exception occurrs only during an assingment.

In this exact code above, we are capable to get away for some time because of type erasue. It is a very tricky case we ended up with. So this is how the bytecode looks like for this method:

```
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: iconst_5
         6: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/Object
         9: putfield      #7                  // Field field:[Ljava/lang/Object;
        12: return
```

Notice - **there is no even `checkcast` bytecode instruction**, becuase there is a redundnat cast, since genericas are erased. Meaning - when use issue the cast at runtime `AnytType` is actually an `Object` in the bytecode, so case from `Object[]` to `Object[]` is no-op.

But! There main method bytecode is this:

```
         0: new           #8                  // class com/example/project/A
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #13                 // Method "<init>":()V
         7: astore_1
         8: aload_1
         9: getfield      #7                  // Field field:[Ljava/lang/Object;
        12: checkcast     #14                 // class "[Ljava/lang/String;"
        15: iconst_0
        16: ldc           #16                 // String Test
        18: aastore
        19: return
```

So, there is a check that fails in the author's case - the 12th instruction. And the reason the code fails with `ClassCastException` can be deduced from `main` method bytecode - becuase there were no actual cast in the constructor, therefore we get the `Object[]` as a type of the `field`, and then JVM tried to cast the `Object[]` into `String[]` like that in the `main` method:

```
((String[])object.field)[0] = "Test";
```

At least this is deduced from the bytecode. And this is pretty logical since we have a generic guarantees here and compiler is just inserting necessary type casts.

And thats were it all fails with `ClassCastException` becuase of the reasons I have already described in the other answer (it was tough to find out, yeah...)